# Android - Moving a single image

Tags: android, image, move

Can anyone help please.

Im writing a small Android game where the player is able to select a "barrier" and drag it accross the screen with their finger. I have the barriers drawn on the screen and I am able to drag it accross the screen. 
My problem however is when I add more than 1 barrier, eg 3 barriers, and drag a barrier accross the screen, they all drag and they all drag to the same position. That is to say they all lie on top of each other, making it look as though there is only 1 barrier.

Here is my code, can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong/explain where I am going wrong.

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, SensorEventListener {

// Initialising the Barrier
private Barrier barrier[] = new Barrier[3];


// The Main Game Panel
public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);

// Adding a call-back (this) to the surfaceHolder to intercept events
getHolder().addCallback(this);

// Creating the Game items
    // The starting coordinates of the Barrier
int x = 30;
int y = 270;
barrier[0] = new Barrier(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blue_barrier), x, y);
barrier[1] = new Barrier(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green_barrier), x + 15, y);
barrier[2] = new Barrier(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pink_barrier), x + 30, y);

// Create the Game Loop Thread
thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

// Make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
setFocusable(true); 
}

// Handles the touch events
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
         int eventAction = event.getAction();

    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    switch (eventAction)
    {
    // Touch down so check if finger is on Barrier
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (x > barrier[0].getX() && x < barrier[0].getX() + 8
                && y > barrier[0].getX() && y < barrier[0].getY() + 8)
        {
            barrier[0].isTouched();
        }
        else if (x > barrier[1].getX() && x < barrier[1].getX() + 8
                && y > barrier[1].getX() && y < barrier[1].getY() + 8)
        {
            barrier[1].isTouched();
        }
        else if (x > barrier[2].getX() && x < barrier[2].getX() + 8
                && y > barrier[2].getX() && y < barrier[2].getY() + 8)
        {
            barrier[2].isTouched();
        }

        break;

    // Touch-drag with the Barrier  
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    // Move the Barrier the same as the finger
        for (int i = 0; i < barrier.length; i++)
        {
            if (barrier[i] == barrier[0])
            {
                barrier[0].setX(x);
                barrier[0].setY(y);
            } // end if
            else if (barrier[i] == barrier[1])
            {
                barrier[1].setX(x);
                barrier[1].setY(y);
            }
            else if (barrier[i] == barrier[2])
            {
                barrier[2].setX(x);
                barrier[2].setY(y);

            } // end else if
        } // end for
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // Finger no longer on Barrier - Do Nothing
        break;
    }
    return true;
}


// Render - Draws the Game Item Bitmaps to the screen
public void render(Canvas canvas)
{
    // Set the background to white
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    barrier[0].draw(canvas);
    barrier[1].draw(canvas);
    barrier[2].draw(canvas);
}


// Update
// This is the Game's update method
// It iterates through all the Objects and calls their update() methods (if they have one)
public void update()
{
} // end update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your barrier move code, you aren't checking a particular barrier is touched, so you're moving all of them to the same coordinates. The following loop does exactly the same thing as your current code:

```
// Move the Barrier the same as the finger
for (int i = 0; i < barrier.length; i++)
    {
        barrier[i].setX(x);
        barrier[i].setY(y);
    } //end for
```

To fix this, you need to check if the current barrier in the loop is the one that was touched, and can change that whole loop to something like:

```
// Move the Barrier the same as the finger
for (int i = 0; i < barrier.length; i++)
    {
        if (barrier[i].isTouched()) 
        {
            barrier[i].setX(x);
            barrier[i].setY(y);
        } // end if
    } // end for
```

You would then need to make sure that you un-set the touched property in the     ACTION_UP section. If you post your Barrier class definition I can probably help more.

Comment: Hi jozzas. Ok I tried your solution but still no luck. Somewhere Im going wrong and still cant figure out where. Maybe its in my Barrier class. Ive included the barrier class here:                    }
  else
  {
   setTouched(false);
  } // end else
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem could be solved by making the barriers three separate objects instead of in an array.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but still got the same problem. Im at my wits end with this.

Comment: That doesn't make sense...  they are 3 instances of the type, just stored in an array.  That wouldn't change the behavior at all.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, your code in handling the move is wrong because it moves all the Barriers to the same X,Y when it should only move the one that is touched.

Also, you are never resetting the `isTouched` on the objects in the Action up.  When the user lifts their finger you should set them all to `isTouched == false`.  If you don't do that then once you touch one it will always move to the X,Y.